How to Record MS Edge Tab?
A few years ago there was a way to record the activity I was doing in a tab on Microsoft Edge. I have forgotten how to do it.
It was a key combination involving the letter 'G' I think.
Then you pressed a red record button and it would tape the activity I was doing inside the open tab. It would record sound as well.
I am certain it was built into Edge without any plugins.
Does anyone know what it was?

Win+G is for the Xbox "Game Bar" which is how Microsoft integrates screen recording in recent Windows versions, so I'd guess this is what you're remembering. It is not "built in" to Edge, but to Windows, and it still is.

I'm not aware of any built-in screen recorder in the Edge browser. However, Windows has a built-in screen recorder that is generally found in the Xbox "Game Bar", which you access using Win + G.
